# How to do some checking not relate any individual file in ESlint plugins?

Tags: plugins, eslint

I want to write an ESLint plugin which can check if some required files are existed or not. The plugin provides a rule and user can configure it and provide some file names.

But the problem is, if I define it as a rule, it will be invoked for every passing file, and it will run multiple times.

Is there a way in ESLint I can do the checking which is not relate with any individual files?

Comment: Seems like it's not possible since ESLint doesn't provide such an extension point to do such checkings

Comment: Why do you want it as an ESLint plugin? ESLint is a static analyzer for JavaScript code.

Comment: @mysticatea I want to do such checking in just one tool

Comment: You can't do this in ESLint. ESLint is not generic style checking tool, it's static **code** analyzer for JavaScript.